# Background images and UIWebView

Tags: ios5, uiwebview, uiscrollview, uiimage

I was able to add a background image to by TableView DetailView but my solution is most certainly incorrect. I have a UIScrollView that contains a UIWebView. When I touch and drag the UIWebView I can see the background image underneath, on the UIScrollView. Other than that it looks great.

What should I try?

Here's the code that does the view:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   

    //...


 /*#####################################################
 *
 * Initialize Scroll & HTML View
 *
 #####################################################*/
 CGRect bounds = [ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] applicationFrame ];
 CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
 CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
 CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;


 UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:bounds];


htmlView = [ [ UIWebView alloc ] initWithFrame:[scrollView bounds]];
htmlView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,screenWidth,screenHeight);

htmlView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
htmlView.opaque = NO;
UIColor *background = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dark-chalkboard-bg.png"]];
htmlView.backgroundColor = background;


NSString  *htmlString = @"HTML-formatted text goes here";

[htmlView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];

scrollView.contentSize = [htmlView bounds].size;

[scrollView addSubview:htmlView];

//...

}
```

Thanks